# How to implement mouse over animation in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having some difficulties finding a way to implement mouse over animation over a button in Kivy.
There are some answers in the internet though they are kinda old.
I'm using python 3.7.7 version and Kivy 1.11.1.
if you know a piece of code that would help me simplify the process pls share it with me.
Thx.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect mouse motion over a `Button`?

Comment: yeah. 
though I would like an example of an actual mouse over code.
specially, inside the .kv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to detect mouse over. I am not aware of a way to do it in `kv`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        id: butt
        text: 'The Button'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
'''


class MouseOverApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_motion)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_motion(self, src, mouse_pos):
        if self.root.ids.butt.collide_point(*mouse_pos):
            print('over Button at', mouse_pos, 'Do animation')


MouseOverApp().run()
```